# Residuals standard deviation

Tags: r, variance, standard-deviation, residuals

What's the difference and the meaning of these two standard deviations:

- `sd(residuals(mod2))` and
- `sigma(mod2)`?

[image: Aonva - sigma - sd]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/sigma.html) for sigma and notice that is scaled by NN-PP where PP is the number of parameters estimated (length of coefficients). It extracts the “residuals standard errors” (as names in the docs) from the output summary, indeed look also at the definition of sigma [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/summary.lm.html) in the summary. Instead sd just calculates the sample standard dev of the input series (here you input residuals), so it divides by NN-1 as usual (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/sd))

Comment: The underlying idea is right; but strictly speaking, it is $\hat\sigma^2,$ not $\sigma,$ that is scaled by $1/(n-p),$ not by $n-p.$

Comment: Yes sure, it was to highlight the scaling. It’s the way they scale the sum of squared res. All formulas are in the docs. I keep writing from the mobile App where I get terribly annoyed posting formulas